# serenity with cucumber Retry feature

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I would like to retry the failed test for my Serenity BDD with Cucumber Acceptance Tests. As per the Serenity Documenation, I see there is a section for retry but it seems to be junit specific. Here are two props it has listed for junit retry:

max.retries=4
junit.retry.tests=true

How should I achieve same retry logic for Serenity with Cucumber? I tried following two props in serenity property file, but none of the two seems to be working.

test.retry.count.cucumber=3
test.retry.count=4

Version Using:
serenity.version - 1.9.6
serenity.cucumber.version - 1.9.4

I will appreciate if anyone knows what additional thing am I missing.